# Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT Live Example In Android

Tags: android

Can any one tell me the the working of Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT Live Example

now what I am doing just creating three activity that are A,B,C

so When I am Launching Application from activity A and from A I am Starting Activity B with startActivityForResult(Activity B) and there In B Activity I am starting activity C with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT and finishing B Activity,so now from there in Activity C When I finished to Activity C it gives result back to the Activity  A in onActivityResult().

So i want to know that is this the purpose of using this flag or that is something different and if I am wrong please let me know.

and please try to give answer with example.

Answer (score 9):

Virendra, your assumptions are correct. This gist demonstrates a simple use case: https://gist.github.com/mcelotti/cc1fc8b8bc1224c2f145. Please note the use of `setResult()` in ActivityC before it is finished.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is already on the stackoverflow .I hope you may understand the logic .

I suggest you to  go with this solution [flag activity @stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360853/third-activity-called-returns-its-result-to-the-first-activity-instead-of-sendin).

Comment: I Got It but can you tell me the live example of it that where we can used it